create react app npx create-react-app my-app it shows theses what should i do
>   npx create-react-app my-app
>     Need to install the following packages:
>     create-react-app@5.0.1
>     Ok to proceed? (y)
>     
>     npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
>     npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
>     npm warn deprecated fstream-ignore@1.0.5: This package is no longer supported.
>     npm warn deprecated rimraf@2.7.1: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
>     npm warn deprecated uid-number@0.0.6: This package is no longer supported.
>     npm warn deprecated fstream@1.0.12: This package is no longer supported.
>     npm warn deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.


Don't use CRA. If you're building a simple SPA to serve statically, switch to Vite (I wrote more about this here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2023/Dec/17/js-tdd-vite.html).

Short Answer: Ignore these warning and work on your project
Want a Longer Answer? Keep reading below...
This shows that create-react-app or packages installed by this uses deprecated dependencies. This will not affect you development if you are just starting out react development. In any case you have following ways to proceed:

Proceed Anyway
You can continue using this as these won't prevent you from working if you are just starting out or your project is not highly critical.

Use any react app creator e.g. vite
Although it doesn't guarantees that you will not get these warning while using vite but you can try npm create vite@latest my-app -- --template react 

Update the deps manually (Might break react or related packages in you project)
You can use npm-check-updates package to manually check for deps and update them.
Install it using npm install -g npm-check-updates and then run ncu -u and npm install in your project folder. This will find and update to newer versions of dependencies but it might break the packages that specifically depend on older versions.


So you best bet is to ignore these warnings and go on.

While these warnings indicate that certain packages are no longer supported and may have issues, they don't necessarily prevent you from creating a new React app.
You can type y and then enter to continue. Despite of the warning it should still work.
Alternative approach which I would like to suggest is

npx create-react-app@latest my-app

This make sure that you are using the latest version of create-react-app
